# How to enable WordPress plugin activation after checking the variable for truth

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to make it possible to activate the plugin developed by me only after the condition with the variable is true. Variable data is pulled from the database.

```
$results = get_option( 'stp_api_settings');
$test_result = $results['stp_api_text_field_0'];
```

Now, if $test_result returns a non-zero value, the true, plugin is activated; if there is no value, a false, error message is displayed.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'check_for_register_key' );
function check_for_register_key()
{

    $results = get_option( 'stp_api_settings');
    $test_result = $results['stp_api_text_field_0'];

    if ($test_result === true ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'error_notice' );
        deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); 
        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) {
            unset( $_GET['activate'] );
        }
    }
}

function register_plugin_notice(){
?><div class="error"><p>The plugin is not registered, go to the options page and enter the activation 
key.</p></div><?php
}
```

But it does not work: The plugin is registered in any case, regardless of the value of the variable. Help solve the issue, please.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include details of the problem you are having? Are you getting an error message? Is the plugin *never* getting registered even if `$test_result` is true? Is it *always* getting registered even if `$test_result` is false? Are you getting a blank screen?  "It does not work" doesn't give us much to go on :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Now the plugin is registered in any case, regardless of the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189208/check-for-dependent-plugin-and-if-false-dont-activate-plugin).
You need to use `register_activation_hook` callback function to do some logical representation before plugin activation